# How would I make a bot self deafen itself?

Tags: discord.js

I am currently trying to make the bot deafen itself as soon as it joins into a voice channel. 
I've tried

```
client.ws.voice.setSelfDeaf(true)
```

I've also been told to use

```
client.ws.send()
```

but I have no idea how to use it.
Is there any way I could do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`client.ws.voice` and `client.ws.send()` are not a thing.

What you need to do is to use [`voice.setSelfDeaf(true)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setSelfDeaf) when the bot joins a voice channel.

```js
voiceChannel.join()
  .then(connection => {
      connection.voice.setSelfDeaf(true);
  });
```