# serverDeafen discordbot | discord/js

Tags: discord, discord.js

ok. I have a discord music bot, and I want to **Server Deafen** the bot whenever it joins the channel, I already did `.setSelfDeaf(true)`, but couldn't find anything for `serverDeafen`

here is the code i use as `.setSelfDeaf(true)` :
`await queueConstruct.connection.voice.setSelfDeaf(true);`

I also tried this for serverDeafen after that : `await queueConstruct.connection.voice.serverDeaf;`
but it didn't work!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *server deafen the bot*? Also, what version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How would I make a bot self deafen itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459698/how-would-i-make-a-bot-self-deafen-itself)

Comment: im using discord.js v12.2.0, and i mean serverDeafning, the link u sent. is for deafning by the bot it self !, you can server deafen a bot and even a user in discord, and im talking about that deafen!

Comment: So you want to deafen everybody?

Comment: no, only the bot (client itself)

Comment: Then what is wrong with the bot deafening itself?

Comment: Do you mean [`VoiceState.setDeaf()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setDeaf)?

Comment: look, i use deafening the bot it self to reduce the vps bandwith, but the bot deafning it self is not working and actually i tried the server deafning manually, it worked so well, so that's my problem with bot Deafning it self on own, not in the server....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the [`.setDeaf()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setDeaf) method?

```js
VoiceChannel.join()
  .then(connection => {
    connection.voice.setDeaf(true)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```